# Unable to remove item from list of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm using the following code to retrieve a list of objects from firebase.  I need to remove an item from the list but I keep getting -1 for the index.  What am I doing wrong here?

```ts
filterItineraries(filters: any): any {
  let num = 0;
  this.allItineraries = [];
  this.filteredItineraries = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      num = 0;
    } else {
      num = (filters.numberOfDays - 1);
    }

    const query = this.dataSvc.getAllItineraries()
        .where('destination', '==', filters.destination)
        .where('dateRange', 'array-contains', filters.dateRange[num]);

    query.get()
        .then(itineraryListSnapshot => {
          this.allItineraries = [];

          itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
            this.allItineraries.push({
              id: snap.id,
              jobCode: snap.data().jobCode,
              destination: snap.data().destination,
              startDate: snap.data().startDate,
              endDate: snap.data().endDate,
              workDetails: snap.data().workDetails,
              userId: snap.data().userId
            });

            const index: number = this.allItineraries.indexOf(filters.id);

            if (index !== -1) {
              this.allItineraries.splice(index, 1);
            }

            console.log('index', index);
            console.log('filters.id', filters.id);
            console.log('filteredItineraries',  this.allItineraries);
          });
        });
  }
}
```

console.log
[image: console.log]

I've also tried moving it outside of the for loop but index = -1.

And lastly I've tried:

```ts
this.filteredItineraries = this.allItineraries;
const index: number = this.filteredItineraries.indexOf(filters.id);

if (index !== -1) {
  this.filteredItineraries.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log('index', index);
console.log('filters.id', filters.id);
console.log('filteredItineraries',  this.filteredItineraries);
```

index always = -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn’t doing what you want:

```ts
const index: number = this.allItineraries.indexOf(filters.id);
```

`index` will always be `-1` here, because `allItineraries` is an array of objects, while `filters.id` is (from the look of your console output) a string.

You would need to iterate through `allItineraries` yourself to locate an entry `e` where `e.id === filters.id` (your existing comparison is `e === filters.id`).

---

Instead of iterating yourself though, why not use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) approach?

```ts
this.allItineraries = itineraryListSnapshot
        .filter(snap => snap.id !== filters.id)
        .map(snap => { id: snap.id, ...snap.data() });
```

I’ve also used the [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax which [is supported in TypeScript >= 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest).